# UIButton not Working when the UIview is presented by addsubView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, addsubview

I have added another view controller to a viewcontroller view ,

addsubview works fine, but the button actions in next view are not working.

**crashes with an error [ModelViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xa81d960**

**in View1 : Current view controller UsersViewController class**

```
-(IBAction)openModelView:(id)sender
{
   ModelViewController *modelView= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModelViewController"];

    [self.view addSubview:modelView.view];
}
```

**In View 2 ModelViewController class**

```
-(IBAction)dismissModelView:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ddddddde");
    //[self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It works fine by using presentViewConroller ***`[self presentViewController:modelView animated:NO completion:nil]`*** **works well**,

but ***i need to display first view in background with some partial transparent***

Comment: May be a scope problem ? simply add child controller

[self addChildViewController:self.yourVC];

Comment: yes its working finr thaks alot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the scope problem ,just add the child controller to the root view controller to avoid the crash.

```
    self.view addSubview:modelView.view];
    [self addChildViewController:modelView];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)openModelView:(id)sender
{
   ModelViewController *modelView= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModelViewController"];

    [self.view addSubview:modelView.view];
    [self addChildViewController:modelView];
}
```